# Url rewriting using subdomain value in Undertow

Tags: undertow

I want to rewrite urls using subdomain values in Undertow as below:

- x.example.com -> example.com/user/x
- y.example.com -> example.com/user/y

How can I accomplish this in Undertow?

Comment: Could you describe in more details what you are trying to achieve? Do you want clients to redirect from one to the other? Or do you already have the 'user/ controller' and you want to treat all incoming requests with a subdomain as if they were targetting your 'user/ controller'?

Comment: I already have the 'user/' controller and I want to treat all incoming requests with a subdomain as if they were targeting your 'user/' controller

Comment: You can create a handler that parses the hostname, using the HttpServerExchange.getHostName() method. If it starts with "x." you add "x" as a query parameter to the exchange then you invoke your already existing 'user/' handler.